# Push values from multiple objects to array

Tags: javascript

I would like to know the best way to push values from multiple objects to an array while keeping them unique.

For example:

```
let emails = [];

owners.map(data => {
    emails.push(data.mail)
})

members.map(data => {
    emails.push(data.mail)
})

console.log(emails)
```

`emails` gets populated with the emails from each object, but they are duplicates. I know how to filter an array for duplicates, but I want to see more options for the above code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) combine both arrays to a single array, and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to an array of emails. Convert the array to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicates, and spread back to array:

```js
const members = [
  { mail: 'a@b.com' },
  { mail: 'c@d.net' },
];

const owners = [
  { mail: 'a@b.com' },
  { mail: 'e@f.org' },
];

const emails = [...new Set([...members, ...owners].map(data => data.mail))];

console.log(emails)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ori mentioned, use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
const emails = new Set();

owners.map(data => {
    emails.add(data.mail)
})

members.map(data => {
    emails.add(data.mail)
})

console.log(Array.from(emails)) //if you need it back to array
```